# How to handle shadowdom in SeleniumWebdriver Script

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, shadow-dom

I have a drop down with 3 choices , I am able to click on the drop down and view the choices but not able to click on the Choice using Webdriver Scripts

I have tried to use JS Executor to identify the Drop down choice. But looks like it is a shadow-root defined , I am not able to click it using .click()

here is the screen shot of the html content for *LookUp Customer*

[![inspect element screen shot][2]][2]

````
var Thr=JavaImporter(java.lang.Thread)//import Thread sleep packages

var wait = new pkg.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,60) //import WebDriverWait Package

var dropdown = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//*[@id="select-work"]')).click()

var lastMessage = WDS.browser.executeScript('return document.querySelector("#select-work").shadowRoot.querySelector("#ink-select > option:nth-child(3)")._value').click()

WDS.log.info('lastMessage is: ' + lastMessage)```



We are not able to click on the look up customer dropdown


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyqCG.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGvD1.png
````

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience Selenium doesn't go well with Angular Js Automation. I would recommend using a selenium-based tool for Angular which is  [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/)

Please check it out and let me know if any other help required on that

Also, we can try using an index to select drop down rather than click and select. below is c# code for it

```
    var dropdown = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("")); // replace "" with xpath of dropdown
    var selectElement = new SelectElement(dropdown);
    selectElement.SelectByIndex(1); //pass your required index in parameter
```